# Flip Fluid add on : Fluid sim freeze while rendering

Tags: fluid-simulation, cache

I baked my fluid simulation, and rendered. But every 15~20 frames the sim froze.

So I closed the Blender file, reload it again and render from the keyframe which was frozen. I think it's the directory(cache) problem?

https://blenderartists.org/t/fluid-sim-freezes/435355/8

This is another post with the same issue in 2008. I cannot believe it hasn't been fixed yet.. anyone has the same issue?

Comment: That's a third-party addon so it might be worth looking at their [FAQ](https://flipfluids.com/faq/) page and putting in a support request assuming it's the paid-for version..

Answer (score 2):

This type of issue can be caused by a known issue in Blender that can result in static renders, incorrect renders, and crashes when rendering a FLIP Fluids addon simulation.

The solution is to render from the command line which ensures a correct and stable render. The FLIP Fluids addon contains a sidebar operator for automatically setting up and launching a command line render here:

[image]

More information can be found in the FLIP Fluids addon documentation here: [Why render from the command line?](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Helper-Menu-Settings#why-render-from-the-command-line)

> **Why render from the command line?**
> There can be render instabilities in Blender that may cause crashes,
> result in incorrect renders, or result in whitewater particles not
> rendering when rendering FLIP Fluids addon simulations. This is caused
> by a design issue in Blender where the viewport and render threads do
> not sync correctly and can cause a crash (Issue [T60094](https://developer.blender.org/T60094) and Issue
> [T88811](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/88811)). This becomes more troublesome as amount of geometry
> increases. This issue is the reason why the viewport needs to be
> locked during render to improve stability. Rendering from the command
> line will bypass this design issue since the viewport is no longer
> needed.
>
> Unfortunately this issue is outside of our control and will need to be
> fixed by the Blender developers. There is a [comment here](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-addons/issues/60094#issuecomment-39925) in the issue
> thread where a Blender developer mentions the design issues will need
> to be handled in regular development:
>
> > From Sergey: Currently it's as stable as we can make it. It is indeed
> > true that interface is better be locked, otherwise render thread might
> > cause conflicts with the viewport (due to python handlers possibly
> > modifying data while it's being drawn by the viewport). There are ways
> > around it, but needs some design changes. Will be handled outside of
> > the bug tracker as a regular development.
>
> This issue can be highly dependent on the system. Some artists will
> experience this issue frequently while others may never experience
> this issue. Due to this issue, we highly recommend becoming familiar
> with the command line rendering tools.

---

Another cause of this issue can be from other addons. If this issue persists after a command line render, try disabling other addons to narrow down the source of the issue.