Flip Fluid baked simulation will not render
I have created a flip fluid simulation in Blender 4.0. I have saved the file immediately post-baking. I can replay the 250 frame animation in the viewport, but when I render, the simulation fails to occur.
The falling obstacle simply passes through the fluid mesh. Then, when I stop the render and return to the viewport the simulation fails to work there as well.
The only recourse I have is to close the file without saving and re-open it whereupon I am presented with the simulation working in the viewport as before.
The fact that the mesh shows up but does not react to the falling obstacle tells me I have done something wrong, but I cannot figure out what.


Would you at the very least show us some screenshot of your cache settings? But as a wild guess, have you set the cache Type to Replay?

If I choose a frame midway through the simulation and render just that frame, it will render correctly. Only when I try to start at the beginning does it fail.

Well, FLIP Fluids is a paid third-party addon, this is off-topic here and you should contact the developers to seek help. I just thought you might be using Blender's own Mantaflow simulation (because just a few days ago someone asked a question about "flip fluid simulation" but was actually using Mantaflow).

Thanks. I actually got the render to work. I used the Flip Fluids pop up menu in the 3d viewerport to call the render instead of Blender's render animation command. It worked. No idea why, but it is likely to be a conflict between FF and Blender. Thanks for your help.

Hey, incorrect renders or stability issues when rendering a FLIP Fluids addon simulation can be caused by a current bug in Blender. Rendering from the command line is the solution to this type of issue. More info in this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302155/flip-fluid-add-on-fluid-sim-freeze-while-rendering/302158#302158
